# LINQ to ComboBox XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, combobox

I'm trying to bind some data to a ComboBox. I looked up some information, but all of the solutions I found so far are not satisfactory. My aim is to create a LINQ query that selects all the required data I want. After that, I would like to populate my ComboBox with the data.

So, my query should be something like this:

```
var result = from p in db.PriorityTypes select new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name };
```

And the in my CombBox I would like to have something like SomePropery={Binding data}. Is this possible? I'm using the WPF technology.

**Note**
So, the ComboBox should be a dropdown of strings, and the values should be their ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ComboBox` uses the `ItemsSource` property for this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ValuePath="Id" />
```

Code behind/view model:

```
// You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface properly here:
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Items { get; set; }
```

Updating the `ComboBox` items is as easy as this:

```
var result = from p in db.PriorityTypes select new YourDataType(p.Id, p.Name);
Items = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>(result);
```

If you've correctly implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and defined a data type class (to replace the `YourDataType` entries above), then this is all you need.